# pick subset of nodes from a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming

Given a tree with n nodes each having some value in it.Find a subset of nodes such that the nodes picked in the subset has a maximum value and each node picked in the subset has even number of children.Here is a recursive solution that I thought of

```
func recurce(node)
  if(node is null) return 0
  exclude_current_node = sum of recurce of all node's children
  //satisfy even number of child property 
  if(odd number of childeren's)
      include_current_node = sum of recurce of all node's children except child with lowest value+value of node
  else
      include_current_node = sum of recurce of all node's children+value of node
  return max(exclude_current_node,include_node)
```

> Is this solution correct?
>
> I can cache the result using dynamic programming to improve runtime.

Comment: Please rephrase the question a bit; having zero children also means having an even number of children, as zero is even. Do you actually mean _an even number of children_ or _an even number of children which are contained in the subset?_

Comment: Well you could flatten the tree into an array of nodes. And then iterate through the nodes and add the node to your subset if and only if it has even children and a positive value

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya we cannot only pick node children with even no of nodes, we can also pick nodes with odd no of children by removing one children with least value and making it even.